# What to do when you have different amount of data in different classes?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I'm working on an age classification problem. When I created classes, based on age group, different age groups have a different number of images. One has only around 1100 pictures and another has around 4500 pictures. I know 1100 pictures are not enough for a class. How do I make more data on the class that has less data? Is there a way to make good data artifacts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you work from face images. To perform data augmentation on these images, you can:

- rotate a little the image,
- modify tilt and slant (a little)
- crop (a little)
- flip left-right
- add noise (salt and pepper, Gaussian...)
- change luminosity

And of course, **mix** two or more of the above processes. See [imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) for example.

With more work, you can try style transfer on your images or modify them with GANs. See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.11685)